# UIImageToMat() retains data from previous calls

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, opencv, memory-management

I am using OpenCV on iOS.

When I run the `grabCut` function below in a `.mm` file and supply:

a green "I" for `inclStrokesImg` [image]

a red "E" for `exclStrokesImg`, [image]

I expect to see a white "I" and "E" for `inclStrokesDebug` and `exclStrokesDebug` respectively, but now I am seeing

an "I" for `inclStrokesDebug" (expected)
[image]

but an "IE" for `exclStrokesDebug` (incorrect, expect to see E only)
[image]

```
cv::Mat cvt2Mask (UIImage * img) {
    cv::Mat mask ;

    if (img == nil){
        return mask;
    }
    UIImageToMat(img, mask);
    cv::cvtColor(mask, mask, CV_RGBA2GRAY);
    cv::threshold(mask, mask, 1, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);

    return mask;
}

+(UIImage *)grabCut:(UIImage *)srcImg withMask:(UIImage *)maskImg andInclusiveStrokes:(UIImage *)inclStrokesImg andExclusiveStrokes:(UIImage *)exclStrokesImg {
    // Returns an inclusive mask image

    cv::Mat src;
    UIImageToMat(srcImg, src);

    cv::Mat mask = cvt2Mask(maskImg);
    cv::Mat inclStrokes = cvt2Mask(inclStrokesImg);
    cv::Mat exclStrokes = cvt2Mask(exclStrokesImg);

    #ifdef DEBUG
    UIImage * maskDebug = MatToUIImage(mask);
    UIImage * inclStrokesDebug = MatToUIImage(inclStrokes);
    UIImage * exclStrokesDebug = MatToUIImage(exclStrokes);
    #endif

    ...

    return ...;
}
```

I checked the `cvt2mask` function, the `UIImageToMat()` went wrong and returned a result combined with previous results.

I ran the `grabCut` function again with the same parameters, the `inclStrokesDebug` will now return "IE" instead of "I" that I saw in the first call.

Is it due to some memory not released issues?

Answer (score 1):

Problem seems fixed when I supply the alpha bool, for unknown reasons. I am using OpenCV 3.4.4

```
cv::Mat cvt2Mask (const UIImage * img) {
    ...
    UIImageToMat(img, maskX, true);
    ...

    return maskX;
}
```